I need to change specific value which i have getting from firestore collection
I need to change specific field name which i have getting from firestore collection in flutter-flow
In this SomeModel is document return type. I am not able to create same class which have same properties of CircleRecord collection.
1.Firstly i am getting data from firebase and store in querySnapshot variable.
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('collection-name')
    .where("data", arrayContains: userRef)
    .get();

2.Then i have create empty list which have store new data.
List<SomeModel> x = [];

3.Then after applying map for getting each doc to store each record in circles list.
x = querySnapshot.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot doc) {
  return SomeModel.fromSnapshot(doc);
}).toList();

4.After that applying forEach for circles to changing specific field value.
x.forEach((data) {
  data.fieldName = 'Hello';
});

5.Then return whole new data list.
return x;


I create custom SomeModel class but it's give error which have say SomeModel model is getting from 2 times. I have also change custom class name but when i return those i am not able to return those type because return type is SomeModel class which i have getting from firebase database.

Hi, could you please share CirclesRecord class. it looks like circleName is final and that's why read-only

Circle Record class is coming from firestore collection it's return type of function.
And i have also try to create same CircleRecord class which have use by firestore collection but it's giving those type of error : https://prnt.sc/PDOV2c4PQEoA
